# Where is the Valparaiso bus station?

Tags: buses, chile, locate-this, valparaiso

I'm traveling to Santiago via bus from Valparaiso, and need to get to the main bus station. Where is it?

There seems to be a lot of conflicting information out there; searching for [valparaiso bus station](https://www.google.com/search?q=valparaiso%20bus%20station) or [estacion de buses valparaiso](https://www.google.com/search?q=estacion%20de%20buses%20valparaiso) yields the Vina del Mar bus station and a TripAdvisor forum result with the wrong address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Horario de Buses](http://www.horariodebuses.cl/terminal-de-valparaiso.html) the bus terminal is called "Terminal Rodoviario de Valparaíso" and the Google Maps insert calls it "Copropietarios Terminal Rodoviarío de Valparaíso". [Romani Buses](http://www.busesromani.cl/site/agencias) calls it "Ag.Terminal Valparaiso". It seems the correct address is

> Av. Pedro Montt 2831, Valparaiso, Región de Valparaíso

Which looks to be right next to Google Map's entry for [Terminal Rodoviario Valparaiso](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Terminal+Rodoviario+Valparaiso/@-33.0473835,-71.6089979,17z/data=!4m5!1m2!3m1!2sTerminal+Rodoviario+Valparaiso!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x0df65432b23a35d2) (though they list the address as Pedro Montt 2860). Either address should be close enough.

I've submitted an update to Google Maps for the correct address.

Comment: I confirm that your answer is correct.